# Using GetRows method to populate array with only certain fields from a recordset?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I have VBA code in an Access database that is supposed to open an Excel file and copy only certain fields from a recordset into it. I am trying to use the GetRows method to specify which fields I want to copy and also directly populate an array with the data from the recordset. I then copy the array to the Excel file.

The problem is that the array is always empty after my GetRows statement. I am not sure why. If I just use rng.CopyFromRecordset I get all the data, so I know the recordset has records in it. I tried to follow the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/getrows-method-ado?view=sql-server-ver16).

Can anyone tell me where I went wrong?

```
Sub ExportToExcel(rs As Object)
    
    Dim filepath As String
    Dim objExcel As Excel.Application
    Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
    Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim arr, headerArr As Variant
    
    filepath = "C:\Desktop\Tracker.xlsx"
        
    Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")    
    objExcel.ScreenUpdating = True 
    objExcel.Visible = True       

    Set wb = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(filepath)
    Set ws = wb.Sheets(1)
    
    'look for last row containing data
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    'specify fields to copy from recordset
    headerArr = Array("field1", "field2", "field5")

    'populate array with recordset data
    rs.MoveLast
    rs.MoveFirst
    arr = rs.GetRows(, , headerArr)

    'copy array to excel file, starting in column C
    ws.Range("C" & lastRow + 1).Resize(UBound(arr, 2) + 1, UBound(arr, 1) + 1).Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(arr)

    'clean up
    wb.Close SaveChanges:=True
    Set ws = Nothing
    Set wb = Nothing
    Set headerArr = Nothing
    Set arr = Nothing
    objExcel.Quit
    Set objExcel = Nothing
    
End Sub
```

Comment: How large is your recordset?

Comment: That approach works for me in general.  Do you need the MoveFirst/MoveLast?

Comment: Why bother with array? Why not just use CopyFromRecordset method? All you need for the range reference is the top left cell. `ws.Range("C" & lastRow + 1).CopyFromRecordset rs`. Of course, the recordset must pull only the desired fields.

Comment: @June7 - OP doesn't want all of the fields.  They already mention using `CopyFromRecordset`

Comment: Guess that's my point. Why not limit data pulled by recordset? AFAIK, GetRows in VBA has only 1 argument: `arr = rs.GetRows(rs.RecordCount)`. The cited documentation specifies SQLServer and VB. However, Access 2013 may have expanded to 2 arguments https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/recordset-getrows-method-dao

Comment: Nope, after finishing review of that article, still just one argument. So, my conclusion is the posted code is not using GetRows supported by Access VBA. Back to recommendation to eliminate array and limit the recordset. In fact I tried to use 3 arguments and then Debug/Compile and Access crashes. I don't see how code can even execute.

Comment: I was assuming an ADO record set (not DAO) which does support GetRows with the additional parameters.  OP will need to clarify…

Comment: When you execute the query that builds the recordset, why don't you limit the fieldlist via SQL statement?

Comment: @FunThomas The query that builds the recordset doesn't limit the field list because the entire recordset is exported to a different excel file elsewhere (different excel files for different people to use)

Comment: @TimWilliams The recordset is DAO. Does that mean GetRows isn't supported the way I'm trying to use it? Also the recordsets are not very large. Usually no more than 50 records.

Comment: @TimWilliams I'm using MoveFirst because the recordset is being used elsewhere in the program and I want to make sure to go back to the top before I start populating my array with its data. Not sure if I need the MoveLast right before it though; that was something I read somewhere else

Comment: [DAO.GetRows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/recordset-getrows-method-dao) only has 1 optional parameter (NumRows).

Answer (score 0):

@CDP1802 was right in that the DAO.GetRows method only supports 1 optional parameter, so I was using the method incorrectly. They suggested iterating through the recordset instead in order to fill my array. I altered their solution a bit and came up with this, which does work for me. I don't know how much the ReDim's in their version of the do while loop would affect the performance, but I figured I would skip that and just directly specify which columns to copy in my version of the loop.

```
Sub ExportToExcel(rs As Object)
    
    Dim filepath As String
    Dim objExcel As Excel.Application
    Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
    Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim lastRow, rowIndex, numCols As Long
    Dim arr As Variant
    
    filepath = "C:\Desktop\Tracker.xlsx"
        
    Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")    
    objExcel.ScreenUpdating = True 
    objExcel.Visible = True       

    Set wb = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(filepath)
    Set ws = wb.Sheets(1)
    
    'look for last row containing data
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    'populate array with recordset data
    numRows = rs.recordCount 
    numCols = 3  'there are 3 columns in the tracker file
    rs.MoveFirst
    ReDim arr(1 To numRows, 1 To numCols)  
    rowIndex = 1

    'copy specific fields from each row in recordset to arr
    Do While Not rs.EOF
        arr(rowIndex, 1) = rs.Fields("field1").Value
        arr(rowIndex, 2) = rs.Fields("field2").Value
        arr(rowIndex, 3) = rs.Fields("field5").Value
        rowIndex = rowIndex + 1
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop
    
    'copy arr to tracker file
    ws.Range("A" & lastRow + 1).Resize(numRows, numCols).Value = arr

    'clean up
    wb.Close SaveChanges:=True
    Set ws = Nothing
    Set wb = Nothing
    Set arr = Nothing
    objExcel.Quit
    Set objExcel = Nothing
    
End Sub
```